# Raspberry Pi 3 - How to install FFMPEG using python newest version

Tags: python, raspberrypi, ffmpeg, h264, transcode

I'm trying to install FFMPEG on Raspberry Pi 3, with libx265 support (H265 coding).
The main purpose is to batch transcode h264 videos on my HD and convert them to h265 to save space on disk.

I found this useful guide https://gist.github.com/enzanki-ars/7d67996a90883e928bc1dd2db7ef0351

But at the moment i get an error regarding libx265-dev during configure procedure (line 116 in the link above): if you look into configure file (inside ffmpeg unpacked folder) you find

```
require_cpp_condition libx265 x265.h "X265_BUILD >= 70"
```

this leads to console error below

```
ERROR: X265_BUILD >= 70 not satisfied

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.
```

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Did you do as it says and report the issue? report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.

Comment: That link is yet another uncredited ripoff of [FFmpeg Wiki: Ubuntu](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu) with a bunch of extra junk added. What's your Ubuntu version? You may have installed x265 that is too old. Why not just install ffmpeg from the repo?

Comment: Please note i'm talking about Raspberry Pi 3 i.e. Raspbian, not Ubuntu. I already tried 'sudo apt-get install ffmpeg' but that ffmpeg gives an error when lounched after installation. That's why i tried to compile it from sources.
Another link that shows a similar procedure is this
https://gist.github.com/sparrc/026ed9958502072dda749ba4e5879ee3